# If we define $L(A) = \det(A)$, $A \in M$, is $L$ a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $L : M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M$ is the set of all square matrices. If we define $L(A) = \det(A)$, $A \in M$, is $L$ a linear transformation?

Attempt: This is not a linear transformation because $L(A + B) = \det(A+B) \neq \det(A) +\det(B)$. Is this correct? Also, if it is not a linear transformation, then is it possible (in higher math) to find some $A$, other than a $1 \times 1$ matrix for $L$ to be a linear transformation?

Comment: It is not homogeneous as well. The determinant is linear with respect to every particular row or a column.  It is $n$-multilinear, where $n$ denotes the rank of the matrix.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Would simple  counter examples easier to follow? For example, let $
A= \left ( \begin{matrix} 

1 & 0  \\
0 & 0  \\ 
\end{matrix}
\right )
$

and

$
B= \left ( \begin{matrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{matrix}
 \right)
$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The above examples can be easily extended to general $n$. For example, for $n=3$, we may take
$
A=\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right )
$,

$
B=\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right )
$ and

$
C=\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right )
$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, $L$ is not a linear transformation.

An easy proof of this is to consider the $n \times n$ identity matrix multiplied by a constant $\lambda$:
$$
\lambda I_n = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Its determinant is obviously $\lambda^n$ but if $L$ were linear, it would have to be
$$
L(\lambda I_n) = \lambda L(I_n) = \lambda.
$$

A note about matrix size: You said you want $M$ to be the set of *all* square matrices. That set isn't very nice to work with, because e.g. you'd have to define the sum of two square matrices of different sizes.

So for the rest of this answer, I will restrict myself to the set $M_n$ of $n \times n$ matrices.

Such a matrix $A \in M_n$ can be considered as a row of column vectors
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
and as such, we can consider $L$ to be a function of these $a_k$'s instead:
$$
L(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = \det \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n \end{bmatrix}.
$$
If you do this, $L$ is linear in *each of the vectors separately*, i.e. it is multilinear:
$$
L(a_1, \dots, a_{k-1}, a_k + \lambda a_k', a_{k+1}, \dots, a_n)
= L(a_1, \dots, a_{k-1}, a_k, a_{k+1}, \dots, a_n) + \lambda L(a_1, \dots, a_{k-1}, a_k', a_{k+1}, \dots, a_n).
$$
(this property is part of the definition and/or can quite easily be proved by using the explicit formula for the determinant)

Alternatively, you can consider $A$ to be a column of row vectors
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
and if you do this, $L$ is also linear in all of the row vectors separately.

This then explains why $L(A + B) \neq L(A) + L(B)$, because
$$
\begin{aligned}
L(A + B) &= L(a_1 + b_1, \dots, a_n + b_n) \\
&= L(a_1, a_2 + b_2, \dots, a_n + b_n) + L(b_1, a_2 + b_2, \dots, a_n + b_n) \\
&= L(a_1, a_2 + b_2, \dots, a_n + b_n) + L(b_1, a_2 + b_2, \dots, a_n + b_n) \\
&= L(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) + L(b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n) + R \\
&= L(A) + L(B) + R \\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $R$ denotes the sum of $L$ evaluated at all other possible combinations of $a_k$ and $b_k$, so for example $L(a_1, b_2, a_3, b_4, \dots)$ is one of the terms in there.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the determinant is not a linear function on $M_n(K)$. However, the determinant is a *group homomorphism*
$$
\det\colon GL_n(K)\rightarrow K^{\times}
$$
between the general linear group and the multiplicative group of the field $K$. Its kernel is $SL_n(K)$, which therefore is a normal subgroup of $GL_n(K)$.